# Can an app developed for android using JAVA run on windows also natively?

Tags: java, android, windows

Can it be run cross platform natively or is there something specific that hinders a JAVA application from being run on PC equally

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to programming which I think should be fairly obvious, so apologies for the dumb question. I'm curious as to how the particulars for app development would work as I'm planning on building an app for android using JAVA and was curious as to whether it could be run on PC also.

Comment: It won't work "out of the box" in the sense that what you'd be missing is the Android SDK/Framework/Classes. The Java code is ultimately Bytecode, but the actual Android classes/SDK isn't all java (there's native/C++ code) and you'd need to obtain a Windows friendly version of all these. It's potentially doable but... why? ;)